# Maven dependency issue - Variable not being populated

Tags: maven

Currently I have two separate projects, but one of the projects depends on the the other. The first project is called *Commons* and is laid out similar to this. There are child projects to this project and everything gets deployed into Nexus correctly.

```xml
    <properties>
        <parentVersion>2.0.0</parentVersion>
    </properties>

    <groupId>Commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>Commons</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${parentVersion}</version>

    ...
```

The second project is similar to the one above, but in the dependencies it's something close to

```xml
    <dependency>
       <groupId>Commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>Commons</artifactId>
      <version>${parentVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I'm doing a Maven build for both of them I'm defining `parentVersion`, so something like

```
    mvn deploy -f pom.xml -DparentVersion=2.0.0
```

Yet, I'm receiving the following error when doing this on the first one:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for Commons.Commons:jar:2.0.0: Failure to find Commons.Commons:pom:${parentVersion} in Repository

So why does it appear it is getting the `${parentVersion}` variable for Commons jar, but failing to find it when it's finding the POM version and just passing the variable and not the variables value?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The project's own version needs to either be inherited or defined explicitly. You can only use this for your dependencies or plugins.

Comment: The first one builds fine by passing in -DparentVersion.

Comment: Actually even parts of the second project are building fine. It isn't until it tries to build one of the child projects that has a dependency on the Commons project. That's when it blows up because it's not getting the value for ${parentVersion}

Comment: try using mvn:help-evaluate to see if it resolves the properties correctly.. and mvn:help-effective-pom to see how the full pom gets constructed.